# Question about the derive of filter roll-off

Tags: filters

I don't understand the follow step in my notes:

It is about the filter roll-off.

$H(w)={1\over 1+j(w/w_c)}$

$\Rightarrow$
$|H(w)|= {1\over \sqrt(1+(w/w_c)^2)}$

where $H(w) = {v_o \over v_i}$

$w_c$ = cut-off frequency

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: why the first step can jump to the second step?

Comment: cross-posted: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/45313/question-about-the-derivation-of-filtering-roll-off

Answer (score 2):

For any arbitrary rational complex function $H(\omega) = \frac{N(\omega)}{D(\omega)}$,

$$
|H(\omega)| = \frac{|N(\omega)|}{|D(\omega)|}
$$

This follows straightforwardly from the properties of the polar (i.e. magnitude/phase) representation of complex numbers. So, for your example:

$$
|H(\omega)| = \frac{|1|}{|1 + j \frac{\omega}{\omega_c}|}
$$

The magnitude of an arbitrary complex number is:

$$
|a + jb| = \sqrt{a^2+b^2}
$$

So for your example:

$$
\begin{align}
|H(\omega)| &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1^2 + \left(\frac{\omega}{\omega_c}\right)^2}} \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + \left(\frac{\omega}{\omega_c}\right)^2}}
\end{align}
$$